# как из бинарника получить байтовый код

Tags: ассемблер, kali-linux, nasm, ld

Есть программа написанная на ассемблере, скомпилирована через компилятор `nasm` и `ld` и вот у меня есть бинарник а как мне из него сделать байтовый код по типу `x66x55xff` есть ли специальный инструмент?

Comment: Да, на любом известном языке написать пару строк.

Comment: Если `x` перед каждой парой цифр не нужен, то посмотрите на [xxd -ps](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd). Также для получения разных "вырезок" в разном формате из ELF-файла (результат трансляции и линковки) полезна утилита [objdump](https://linux.die.net/man/1/objdump)

Comment: Какой формат нужен на выходе? См. srec_cat

Comment: @Mike А можете на примере `python` привести, я просто не знаю как, пробовал через `file=open('exemple','rb');print file.read()` но вышла белиберда

Comment: Да ну его, еще open делать. скучный он. па perl короче :) `perl -npe 's/./sprintf "x%02x", ord $&/ges' имя-файла`. Думаю на питоне что то в том же роде надо делать, читать, брать отдельные символы, получать их коды (ord()) и печатать в шестнадцетиричном виде

Comment: @Mike Но вы бы могли привести пример именно на `python` так как я `perl` не знаю